# Javascript is not working in content

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have javascript that working in form but when I tried to put it on content is not working anymore..

Here's working javascript:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Numeric.aspx.cs" Inherits="Numeric" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.numeric.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <form>
        Numbers only:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input class="numeric" type="text" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#TextBox1").numeric();
        </script>
    </form>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's not working javascript in content:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NumericNew.aspx.cs" Inherits="NumericNew" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.numeric.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" > </asp:ScriptManager>
 <div>

        Numbers only:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input class="numeric" type="text" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#TextBox1").numeric();   
        </script>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Please let me know thoughts.. Thank you.

Comment: Describe "not working". What's supposed to happen? What is happening? Any errors in console? How did you debug your code?

Comment: Please update your title. You can read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Try $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using a master page the control id not remain `TextBox1`

Use `$("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>")`

If you check in firebug or another tool you will realize that the id is like `ctl00_TextBox1`